# Returning a scalar from SQL Server to C# 

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to return scalar from a database like this:

```
DbConnection cn = GetConnection2();
cn.Open();

// stored procedure
DbCommand cmd = GetStoredProcCommand(cn, "GetReason");
DbParameter param;

param = CreateInParameter("Reason_Number", DbType.String);
param.Value = number;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

param = CreateOutParameter("Result", DbType.String);
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

cmd.ExecuteScalar();

string reason;
reason = cmd.Parameters["@Result"].Value.ToString();

if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
   cn.Close();

return reason;
```

Here is my stored procedure:

```
-- =============================================
-- Create date: Today
-- Description: Input Reason # and Return Full Reason Name
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetReason]
    @Reason_Number nvarchar(50),
    @Result nvarchar(50) output  
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT @Result = Field1 
    FROM dbo.Reasons
    WHERE Field1 LIKE @Reason_Number + '%';
END
```

I am getting an error on the `ExecuteScalar` line:

> System.InvalidOperationException occurred
>   Message="String[1]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `ExecuteScalar`, your stored proc needs to return the single row, single column from a `SELECT`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetReason]
    @Reason_Number nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT Field1 
    FROM dbo.Reasons
    WHERE Field1 LIKE @Reason_Number + '%';
END
```

and then your code needs to read that value:

```
var returnedValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

and use it from there. Of course, in that case, you also do not need an OUTPUT parameter in your C# code....

Word of warning: that `SELECT` in your stored proc **could** potentially return multiple rows. You might want to add a `TOP 1` to your select - just to be safe:

```
    SELECT TOP 1 Field1 
    FROM dbo.Reasons
    WHERE Field1 LIKE @Reason_Number + '%';
```

Comment: what changes did you make to the stored proc i dont see it thank you

Comment: I removed the OUTPUT parameter (`@Result`) from the list of parameters, and I changed the `SELECT` statement to just return the value - not assign it to the output parameter

Answer (score 1):

Just add an other one statement to the end of your stored procedure and remove `OUTPUT` parameter

```
SELECT @Result as 'Result'
```